# Binary Nvidia driver broken with Debian Sid / Experimental: GLXBadContext

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently switched away from `sgfxi` after the resulting driver was unable to run OpenGL applications and installed the packaged Debian Experimental (387.x) drivers instead. Unfortunately, they are showing the exact same error as the `sgfxi` one (I think): Most applications at least complain about missing / bad OpenGL, and many refuse to start. In its most verbose form, it looks like this:

```
name of display: :0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  48
  Current serial number in output stream:  47
```

That is the (only) output from `glxinfo` and other such utilities. Most other applications only have the two lines starting with libGL, some also something like "Unrecognized OpenGL version".

Now, Googling quickly results in the conclusion that this is because I'm using the wrong `libGL.so.1`. Unfortunately, I don't really know how the graphics system works, so all I can do is provide you with a wide context and hope someone figures it out or asks the right questions.

Here's `ls /usr/lib/{i386,x86_64}-linux-gnu/libGL*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 317032 Sep 28 22:04 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Jan  7 12:22 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2-i386-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     52 Jan  7 12:22 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so.2-i386-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     48 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-i386-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 497284 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Jan  7 12:22 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_indirect.so.0-i386-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Dec 22 11:25 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0 -> libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 469500 Dec 22 11:25 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Jan  7 12:22 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_nvidia.so.0-i386-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  71300 Sep 28 22:04 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 612808 Sep 28 22:04 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv1_CM.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Jan  7 12:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv1_CM.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     64 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     52 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     54 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so.2-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Aug 24 21:30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.0 -> libGLEW.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 587816 Aug 24 21:30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     48 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     50 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 912570 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 453216 Sep 13  2015 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     63 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_indirect.so.0-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Dec 22 11:25 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0 -> libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 471640 Dec 22 11:25 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Jan  6 23:46 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_nvidia.so.0-x86_64-linux-gnu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov  9 11:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68136 Sep 28 22:04 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
```

And `ls -la /etc/alternatives/*libGL*`:

```
root@icicle:/usr/lib/nvidia# ls -la /etc/alternatives/*libGL*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv1_CM.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Jan  6 23:46 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv1_CM.so-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so.2-i386-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so.2-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Jan  6 23:46 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGLESv2.so-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-i386-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Jan  6 23:46 /etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan  6 23:46 /etc/alternatives/libGL.so-master -> /usr/lib/mesa-diverted
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 60 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2-i386-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_indirect.so.0-i386-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLX_indirect.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_indirect.so.0-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLX_indirect.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_nvidia.so.0-i386-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  7 12:22 /etc/alternatives/nvidia--libGLX_nvidia.so.0-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
```

`galternatives` only has MESA for `libGL.so-master` available, while `update-glx --config glx` says:

```
  Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/nvidia             100       auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/mesa-diverted      5         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia             100       manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/nvidia/bumblebee   95        manual mode
```

Finally, I have these Nvidia packages installed:

```
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                                           0.8.1                               amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libegl-nvidia0:amd64                                             387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL library
ii  libegl-nvidia0:i386                                              387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary EGL library
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:amd64                                    387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:i386                                     387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)
ii  libgles-nvidia2:amd64                                            387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library
ii  libgles-nvidia2:i386                                             387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library
ii  libglx-nvidia0:amd64                                             387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary GLX library
ii  libglx-nvidia0:i386                                              387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary GLX library
ii  libnvidia-cfg1:amd64                                             387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-cfg1:i386                                              387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64                                     387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Wayland EGL external platform library
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:i386                                      387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary Wayland EGL external platform library
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:amd64                                          387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:i386                                           387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-glcore:amd64                                           387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries
ii  libnvidia-glcore:i386                                            387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries
ii  libnvidia-ml1:amd64                                              387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) runtime library
ii  libnvtt2:amd64                                                   2.0.8-1+dfsg-8.1+b1                 amd64        NVIDIA Texture Tools
ii  nvidia-alternative                                               387.34-2                            amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-driver                                                    387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-driver-bin                                                387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:amd64                                         387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:i386                                          387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
ii  nvidia-egl-common                                                387.34-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL driver - common files
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:amd64                                             387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:i386                                              387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-egl-wayland-common                                        387.34-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Wayland EGL external platform - common files
ii  nvidia-egl-wayland-icd:amd64                                     387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA Wayland EGL external platform library (ICD)
ii  nvidia-egl-wayland-icd:i386                                      387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA Wayland EGL external platform library (ICD)
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup                                         20151021+7                          amd64        cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                                             20151021+7                          amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms                                               387.34-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-kernel-support                                            387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-legacy-check                                              387.34-1                            amd64        check for NVIDIA GPUs requiring a legacy driver
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                                  384.98-1                            amd64        utility to load NVIDIA kernel modules and create device nodes
ii  nvidia-persistenced                                              384.98-1                            amd64        daemon to maintain persistent software state in the NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-settings                                                  387.34-1                            amd64        tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-support                                                   20151021+7                          amd64        NVIDIA binary graphics driver support files
ii  nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64                                        387.34-2                            amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix - NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-vulkan-common                                             387.34-1                            amd64        NVIDIA Vulkan driver - common files
ii  nvidia-vulkan-icd:amd64                                          387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA Vulkan installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-vulkan-icd:i386                                           387.34-2                            i386         NVIDIA Vulkan installable client driver (ICD)
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia                                        387.34-2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

This is the output of `grep -iC5 /var/log/Xorg.0.log` (the whole thing would make the post too long:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.5
Release Date: 2017-10-12
[ 24218.534] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 24218.534] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[ 24218.534] Current Operating System: Linux icicle 4.14.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2 (2018-01-06) x86_64
[ 24218.534] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.14.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/icicle--vg-root ro loglevel=1 nvidia-drm.modeset=1 nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0
[ 24218.534] Build Date: 16 October 2017  12:28:38PM
[ 24218.534] xorg-server 2:1.19.5-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[ 24218.534] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 24218.534]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
--

[ 24218.536] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 24218.537] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1380:1462:3102 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 24218.537] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 24218.537] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[ 24218.540] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 24218.540]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 24218.540]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[ 24218.540] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  387.34  Tue Nov 21 02:04:31 PST 2017
[ 24218.540] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 24218.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[ 24218.540] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 24218.540]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 24218.541]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 24218.541] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  387.34  Tue Nov 21 01:38:22 PST 2017
[ 24218.541] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[ 24218.546] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 24218.546] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 24218.546] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 24218.546] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 24218.546]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
--
[ 24218.546]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
[ 24218.546]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 24218.546] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[ 24218.546] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[ 24218.546] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[ 24218.546] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 24218.546] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[ 24218.546] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 24218.546] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 24218.546] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "Off"
[ 24218.546] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[ 24218.546] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "TripleBuffer" "false"
[ 24218.546] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA SLI disabled.
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Coolbits" "8"
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "1920x1080_60 +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x2222; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"
[ 24218.547] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[ 24218.952] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[ 24218.952] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[ 24218.952] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[ 24218.952] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
[ 24218.953] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 750 Ti (GM107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[ 24218.953] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[ 24218.953] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.25.00.53
[ 24218.953] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24218.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24218.967] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24218.967] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24218.967] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24218.967] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24218.969] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[ 24218.969] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "1920x1080_60+0+0{ForceCompositionPipeline=On}"
[ 24218.969] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[ 24218.976] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (95, 94); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[ 24218.976] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[ 24218.976] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[ 24218.976] (II) NVIDIA: Using 6144.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[ 24218.976] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[ 24218.993] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1920x1080_60+0+0{ForceCompositionPipeline=On}"
[ 24219.036] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[ 24219.036] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[ 24219.036] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 24219.036] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[ 24219.036] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinView" is not used
[ 24219.036] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 24219.036] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 24219.036] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 24219.036] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 24219.036] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[ 24219.083] (--) RandR disabled
[ 24219.084] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[ 24219.084] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 24219.084] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[ 24219.122] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
--
[ 24219.192] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 24219.192] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 24219.192] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 24219.192] (II) event3  - (II) Power Button: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 24219.192] (II) event3  - (II) Power Button: (II) device is a keyboard
[ 24219.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[ 24219.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 24219.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 24219.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[ 24219.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 24219.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 24219.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[ 24219.194] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 24219.194] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 24219.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event0)
[ 24219.194] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 24219.194] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
--
[ 24219.408] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.4/3-1.4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/0003:046D:4002.0007/input/input5/event2"
[ 24219.408] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K750" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[ 24219.408] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 24219.408] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 24219.408] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24219.893] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24219.908] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24219.908] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24219.908] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24219.908] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.054] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24220.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24220.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.067] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.443] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.444] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24220.457] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24220.457] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24220.457] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24220.457] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24236.732] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.745] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24236.745] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24236.745] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24236.745] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 24236.871] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 24236.884] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): connected
[ 24236.884] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[ 24236.884] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2353 (DFP-1): 340.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

`apt-file search libGL.so.1` tells me that there are only two possibly relevant packages (if this is the right path at all), but `libgl1-glvnd-nvidia-glx` conflicts with libgl1 on which a lot of applications depend and `libgl1-nvidia-glx` is a legacy version from Oldstable.

Does anyone have the divination skills to tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally. Cost me a day by now, but the issue was that `/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/{i386,x86_64}-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1` pointed to `/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/{i386,x86_64}-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0` instead of `/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/{i386,x86_64}-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0`. I replaced the symlink, ran `ldconfig` and everything appears to work again.

I'd be glad if someone could tell me what that actually means and why it happened, though.

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=879041